# Grouping nodes efficiently?

Tags: php, javascript, containers, grouping, nodes

While most questions are about grouping nodes based on similarity (pidgeonholes), I would like to group nodes based on simply their proximity.

I have a large, dense collection of nodes- Potentially millions. On-screen they take up some amount of space, so they can be thought of as having a size.

What I am trying to do is to group these nodes into single containing nodes efficiently, both in processing time and also in collecting more nodes per container.

My current attempts have either been too slow, or didn't work, but are all based off of the same solution I have in mind: Calculate a lot of possible containers by taking a node and it's surrounding nodes at random and grouping them, then picking the most effective container.

What are your ideas, not specifically in any language, but I will be using PHP or JavaScript for this.

```
Edit
```

I forgot to mention that the nodes will be streamed in, so it needs to accept unlimited nodes, putting them into containers as they come, creating new containers or even deleting them as necessary, for up to millions of containers. That would be the most ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called clustering. You have a set of nodes and a function `m` that calculates the distance between any two nodes. You now search for clusters so that the sum of all the distances between all nodes inside each cluster is minimal.

There are some easy algorithms to do this. Search for [`k-Means`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm) and [`k-Medoid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) for example. These two are very similar to your approach. A more efficient version is the `CLARANS` algorithm [NH94]. I didn't find any good sources for you but here you go:

(German) Script on clustering in general. Contains CLARANS in pseudo-code on page 45
http://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/forschung/gebiete/wbi/teaching/archive/ws1112/vl_datawarehousing/15_clustering_12.pdf

English script that explains CLARANS
http://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/232.pdf

Paper about CLARANS
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~atung/publication/pakdd002.pdf

The "k" in the names is the number of clusters. For those 3 algorithms you have to specify the number of clusters a priori.

For a different approach, see the [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) algorithm. You won't need the number of clusters for this algorithm, but you have to provide some other knowledge of your nodes. The wikipedia article explains this very well. :-)

Comment: I've been using the term Clustering in my own code and it's exactly what I want. Thanks for the algorithms. I'll have a look at them and let you know whether they are suitable solutions.

Comment: Looking at those algorithms I designed one that would work for me, it's a mixture of them. I will place my "k" containers randomly, find the nearest container to each node, mean those groups, and move the container there, repeating it a few times. The part I need to improve is the looping.. Some nodes will be out of range, and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to only loop through the nodes that would be in range of other nodes.. It will be dense, but there may be very sparse areas with nodes way out of range.

Comment: Did you read the article about DBSCAN already? This seems to be what you want.

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't quite fit my ideal.. I will read it more thoroughly if I need to, I.. Scanned it. ;) My ideal is this: I feed a node into a function which puts it into its container, creating a new container if necessary. This way I could stream nodes. It could also move the container if necessary, but I do want it to be capable of handling a stream of nodes. My current idea is to have a grid act like a sheet of cloth, the more nodes in a certain area the more the cloth sags, and the local maxima would be my containers...

Comment: One more node- I want to avoid strange shapes in the clustering, ideally just circles or just convex polygons... When you click on a group, it will zoom in, revealing everything inside, so it needs to be able to nicely fill the viewing area when it's zoomed... It's almost nearest-neighbor, but capable of accepting a stream of nodes with constantly changing container locations.

Comment: So if allowing potential unlimited amounts of nodes, you cannot use algorithms where the number of clusters has to be known beforehand. DBSCAN won't create convex clusters. I would try changing DBSCAN to also determine a center and only include nodes into a cluster if it's distance is not greater than maxDistance. Good luck!